# What other factors maybe causing my php script to timeout?

Tags: php

I have been creating a php script to analyse some data.  At around 320 seconds the script just stops, no error messages.

I have created a separate simple php script to test and ensure its nothing in my code causing the problem.  The simple php script does the same.  I have set the max execution time to 25000 (again only for testing) and it still stops at 300 - 360 secs.  What other factors maybe causing my script to timeout?

```
echo ini_get('max_execution_time');

for ($x = 0; $x <= 600; $x++) {
echo $x." - ";
    sleep(1);
}
```

I would expect the script to continue running for 600 seconds, however its stops at 308.

OUTPUT:-
250000 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 12 - 13 - 14 - 15 - 16 - 17 - 18 - 19 - 20 - 21   .......    299 - 300 - 301 - 302 - 303 - 304 - 305 - 306 - 307 - 308 -

Comment: Perhaps it's the browser that gives up? Maybe you can try it in Ajax and feed the browser enough to keep it interested

Comment: Interestingly, I've just tried the simple script in my original post on my mobile and it times out after 119 seconds.  As you say that points to it being a browser setting.

Comment: run this as a cron-job, it will work fine. The browser gets bored and goes to watch p0rn while waiting for a response from your script.

Comment: Could be the keep-alive value that cause the browser to close the execution, I suggest to use the ob_flush() to send the data to the browser

Comment: You might want to look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php and the max_input_time setting.  I think with the former you can extend the execution time, even though that does not seem to be the problem, and I read something once about there being a bug in PHP with max_iput_time and max_execution time, probably an earlier version.  Also, it may be a server setting.  This is from the PHP docs:  **Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution . .  default to 300 seconds. See your web server documentation for specific details. **

Comment: Probably an Apache or IIS setting given that it says the default is 300 seconds.

Comment: OK I've updated the php.ini and added:-

max_execution_time = 25000,  
max_input_time = 25000 &
default_socket_timeout = 25000.  

I've switched to IE and added the following keys to the registry:- 

KeepAliveTimeout: 24960000 & 
ServerInfoTimeout: 24960000.  

I've added:- 

ob_flush(); & 
flush();.  

However the issues still exists.  I think running it as a Cron Job is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you will have it continue working:

```
set_time_limit(0);
for ($x = 0; $x <= 600; $x++) {
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    echo $x." - ";
    sleep(1);
}
```